# Tolkien's elves and pets

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves

Tolkien's elves have better communication with animals than humans (like riding horses without needing a bridle or other control device) but is there any indication they keep pets?

Comment: Not an elf, but Berúthiel was quite fond of cats.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can think of would be Huan, who was kept by Celegorm as a gift from Oromë, and then later bonded with Lúthien:

> [T]he chief of the wolf hounds that followed Celegorm was named Huan. He was not born in Middle-earth, but came from the Blessed Realm; for Oromë had given him to Celegorm long ago in Valinor, and there he had followed the horn of his master, before evil came.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 19: "Of Beren and Lúthien"</sup>

I include Huan here mainly because he's the only animal I can think of who formed an emotional connection to an Elf, which is to my mind the thing that distinguishes a "pet" from a "kept animal."

Other than this admittedly shaky case, no; there is no evidence that the Elves kept domesticated animal for purely emotional reasons. Even Huan was principally a hunting hound, and would presumably have had a very different relationship to Celegorm than I have to my own dog.

Comment: As an aside, the notion of pets do exist within Middle-earth, though it seems to be more common (or exclusive to) the Shire-Bree area; in *Fellowship* we learn that Bob the Hobbit has a cat, for instance

Comment: And don't forget the cats of Queen Berúthiel.

Comment: There are a few other similes involving cats, including one "(*his cat*, he calls her, but she owns him not)" (*The Two Towers*, Book IV, Chap 9, "Shelob's Lair") that indicates ownership of an animal, but these seem to be artifacts of narration rather than description of what's in Middle-earth. And of course Farmer Maggot keeps dogs; but those aren't necessarily "pets" in the way we often think of the term.

Comment: There is also Farmer Maggot's dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in the Silmarillion nightingales and other birds are mentioned around Melian, the Maia. Even in Menegroth were there birds, so they must live among the elves.